# Force-installed extension on Google Chrome with GPO not working for some extensions (Flashcontrol)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gpo

We use Google Chrome on all our machines and use the Chrome policies in our active directory.

Everything is working fine (HomepageLocation, HomepageIsNewTabPage, ShowHomeButton, ...), but the ExtensionInstallForcelist has some problems.
Not all the extensions are installed on the computers.
We want to install 2 extensions:

- uBlock Origin (is force installed correctly)
- Flashcontrol => **Flashcontrol (extension-ID mfidmkgnfgnkihnjeklbekckimkipmoe is blocked by the administrator**

If we want to install this extensions manually we get the error it's blocked. That's also the reason it's not force-installed.

We didn't activate any blacklist policy:

[image]

With CMD > `gpresult /r` we see that the correct GPO are applied to our computers.

**Google Chrome Version**: 44.0.2403.89

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have spelled the install URI wrong...

It should be

```
https://clients2.google.com
```